# is it possible to install java fx on an android phone?

Tags: java, android, java-me, jvm, javafx

I want to install a Java Me application on my android phone.  I have tried with jbed and some other virtual machines, but it doesn't work.
On Windows Mobile, I tried with javaFx and it worked, so I tried to do the same on android but I cann't find a javaFx apk.
My phone is Samsung GT-i5500.
Thanks.

Comment: You could track the status of this in the issue tracker: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-15401

Comment: awt can running on android you can use this project [AwtonAndroid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366994/install-java-on-android-kitkat-sbc/43949045#43949045)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oracle demoed running JavaFx applications on Android devices at the last JavaOne conference. Supposedly the app would include its own copy of the JVM runtime or so. Nothing is available publically at this stage, but I suspect that something is in the works.

E.g. read more on [Dzone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/javaone-2011-javafx-20)

Update Dec. 2012: It must be getting closer to reality. [JavaFX is now running on a Raspberry Pi,](http://www.java.net/community/javafx/video/javafx-raspberry-pi) (link no longer valid) which uses an ARM chip just like most Android devices. Simply do a [search of Java FX on Raspberry Pi](https://www.google.ca/search?q=javafx%20raspberry%20pi) and you will find lots of references.

Comment: Link **JavaFX is now running on a Raspberry Pi** is no longer valid.

Answer (score 5):

Google created their own JVM for Android (Dalvik) for performance reasons, so as things is now, it's not possible. The JavaFX team claimed earlier that it could run on Android - but I havnt seen it.

Comment: The problem is not that Google created its own JVM, lots of vendors have (like IBM, BEA) for their platform, but that Google's implementation isn't compatible with the specs of Sun/Oracle. When you develop,test and package application on the Oracle JVM, then it should run on the IBM JVM or the BEA JVM with little problems. However, you can't run your application package on Dalvik.

Comment: Not strictly true that Google created Dalvik (It was originally written by Dan Borstein [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_virtual_machine) but adopted by Google and now obviously a core part of Android.

Comment: @cuberoot you make me laugh, Dalvik is just clone of JVM. Dan and the whole android team make an exact copy of an existing system and after that they publish as a new product.

Comment: @OzhanDuz You are mistaken. The only similarity between the Dalvik VM and the JVM is that they both share Java as their primary input language. The Dalvik VM runs an entirely different bytecode set and operates in an entirely different way. The major difference is that it is a register-based VM rather than the JVM which is stack-based. So no, it is not an exact copy of an existing system and certainly not an exact copy of the JVM.

Comment: Google definitely didn't use Dalvik for performance reasons. It is ages behind Hotspot. They used it because Sun JVM was not free yet when they started and probably because they wanted to have more control over it.

Comment: @thomas i wan to deploy javafx app on android.  i tired to use Dalvik VM but not implemented correctly. can you suggest me some way how to do it ?

Answer (score -2):

Not without resorting to rooting or some other non-standard thing. Android runs the Dalvik VM